# c++ sumatoria for

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for

Estoy realizando un programa donde calcula las ventas por día de un vendedor pero en el ultimo bucle for intento que me diga las ventas totales de todos los días , al momento de compilar no tengo ningún problema , pero al momento de la ejecutar el programa no me hace la suma , ¿Me podrían ayudar a saber el por que?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sueldo,dias,dias_laborados,prendas;
    int total=0;

    cout << "¿Cual es el sueldo base del vendedor ?"<< endl;
    cin >> sueldo;
    cout << " ¿Cuantos dias trabajo en la semana?"<< endl;
    cin >> dias;
    int  *array = new int[dias];
int i=0;
    for (i;i < dias; i++)
 {
        dias_laborados=i+1;
    cout << " ¿Cuantas prendas vendio (0-18) en el dia "<<dias_laborados<< endl;
    cin >> prendas;

    if (prendas<4){
        array[i]=sueldo;
        cout << "Su sueldo del dia fue de "<<array[i]<< endl;}
        else if (prendas<8){
        array[i]= (prendas*25)+sueldo;
          cout << "Su sueldo del dia fue de "<<array[i]<< endl;}
        else if (prendas<13){
        array[i]= (prendas*45)+sueldo;
    cout << "Su sueldo del dia fue de "<<array[i]<< endl;}
            else{
        array[i]= (prendas*70)+sueldo;
            cout << "Su sueldo del dia fue de "<<array[i]<< endl;}
}
    for (i;i < dias; i++)
        {
total +=array[i];}
            cout << "Su sueldo total de la semana fue de "<<total<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo del programa ya ejecutado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu variable i, al terminar el primer for se queda con el valor de dias y con ese valor inicial empiezas el segundo for. Tienes que inicializar a 0 la i antes de empezar el segundo for

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza esto

```
int i=0;
for (i;i < dias; i++)
```

Por esto

```
for(int i=0; i<dias; i++)
```

Este cambio deberías hacerlo porque, en primer lugar, no tiene sentido:

```
for( i; ...)
//   ^ ???
```

El bucle `for` te habilita tres campos para poner operaciones:

```
for (INICIALIZACION, CONDICION, INCREMENTOS)
    CODIGO_DEL_BUCLE
```

Realmente el bucle `for` no espera que hagas nada especial en estos campos. Lo único importante para él es que el código que pongas ahí se ejecutará en un momento dado. Un código equivalente al que se genera cuando tu escribes un bucle for sería el siguiente:

```
INICIALIZACION
:bucle resultado=(CONDICION);
if (resultado)
{
    CODIGO_DEL_BUCLE
    INCREMENTOS
    goto :bucle
}
```

Esto quiere decir que en cualquiera de los campos del `for` podrías escribir instrucciones complejas y las mismas se ejecutarán sin problemas:

```
int i;
for(std::cout << "hola\n", i=0; std::cout << "test\n", i<5; std::cout << "incremento\n", i++)
{ }
```

Una vez visto esto, si volvemos a tu código:

```
for (i;i < dias; i++)
```

El código de inicialización `i` **no hace absolutamente nada**. Sería como tener el siguiente código:

```
int i;

i; i; i; i; i; i; i; // <<--- esto no sirve para nada
```

Por otro lado, al declarar la variable fuera del bucle, tu código crea una variable `i` que no se elimina al finalizar el bucle. Esto es un problema, ya que si te da por utilizarla posteriormente y te olvidas de inicializarla de nuevo, el compilador no te informará de nada porque para él no es un error.

En cambio, declarar la variable en el bucle vincula la vida de la variable al propio bucle. Al terminar el bucle la variable dejará de existir y con eso evitarás reutilizar la variable por error.

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
  // ...
}
std::cout << i; // Error: variable no declarada
```

Procura no reutilizar variables, te ahorrarás muchos dolores de cabeza. Es preferible eliminar las variables cuando ya han cumplido su misión